# Xamarin forms - Custom Picker Renderer

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am currently doing a custom render for a picker in ios and using uitextfield for it but apparently it lets you copy and paste with the text in the custom picker after I do a custom render of it in ios. So is there a way to disable UItextfield copy and paste in a custom render ty

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding the CanPerform method in the renderer like this:

```
public override bool CanPerform(ObjCRuntime.Selector action, NSObject withSender)
{
    return base.CanPerform(action, withSender);
    if (action == new ObjCRuntime.Selector("paste:"))
        return false;
    return base.CanPerform(action, withSender);
}
```